# generic API to initialize structs with common fields

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a number of structures, which have first 3 fields common, below is
simplified example:

```
struct my_struct1 {
   /* common fields. */
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
};

struct my_struct2 {
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   uint32_t d;
   uint32_t e;
};

struct my_struct3 {
   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   uint16_t d;
   char e;
};

static void func1(struct my_struct1 *s)
{
   /* ... */
}

static void func2(struct my_struct2 *s)
{
   /* ... */
}

static void func3(struct my_struct3 *s)
{
   /* ... */
}

int main(void)
{
   struct my_struct1 s = {1, 2, 3};
   struct my_struct2 p = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   struct my_struct3 q = {1, 2, 3, 4, 'a'};

   func1(&s);
   func2(&p);
   func3(&q);

   /* XXX */
   func3((struct my_struct3 *)&s);

   return 0;
}
```

Is it safe to typecast `s` to `struct my_struct3 *` and pass to `func3` and ensure that `s` or other objects allocated on stack would not be corrupted?

The reason is that I would like to write a generic API that takes a pointer, initializes common fields (which are common for structures). The other function is specific to `my_struct*` and sets the rest of the fields.

I'm not sure if `void *` can solve this.

**UPDATE**
I should mention, that unfortunately I can't change the structures layout, i.e. adding a common part isn't an option, because the code I'm working with is pretty old and I'm not allowed to change its core structures.

The only ugly workaround I'm seeing is to pass `void *` and `enum struct_type` parameters to `generic_init` function, and based on `struct_type` cast `void *` to appropriate structure.

Comment: No, this is *not* permissible. However, why don't you put the common part into a struct that is then used as the first member of the other structs? You could then convert a pointer to one of those derived structs to a pointer to the base struct.

Comment: Just move the "common fields" into another sub-structure and make it a field of the others. then pass that field to the init function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can interpret the standard, casting a pointer of type `my_struct1*` to a pointer of type `mystruct_3*` or vice vera *may* yield undefined behaviour because of pointer conversion rules (cf. [C11 standard ISO/IEC 9899:TC2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)):

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers ... (7) A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If
>   the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the pointed-to
>   type, the behavior is undefined. ...

Hence, as `my_struct1` and `my_struct3` may have different alignment, a pointer that is correctly aligned according to `my_struct1` does not necessarily be correctly aligned according to `my_struct3`.

But even if you can guarantee that all structs have the same alignment, passing a pointer to an object of type `my_struct1` to `func3` is - in my opinion -
not safe, even if the common members are the first ones in each struct and even if `func3` accesses only the common members.
The reason is that a compiler may introduce padding between members:

> 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers ... (13) Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
>   reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are
>   declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points
>   to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the
>   unit in which it resides), and vice versa. **There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.**

Hence, as `my_struct1` and `my_struct3` have different sets of members, the rules of how a compiler introduces padding may vary between these two structs. I think that it is unlikely that this happens, but I did not find any statement in the standard that guarantees that padding - even for the first three members - is the same for `my_struct1`  and `my_struct3`.

Answer (score 2):

To flesh out what the comments of EOF and Eugene Sh. already explain:

It would not be safe to cast a my_struct1 to a my_struct3, as my_struct3 has more members that my_struct1 and the compiler would not warn at all about accessing those additional members (d and e), overwriting whatever is behind the my_struct1. Doing it the other way around may work, as long as my_struct1 exactly corresponds to the start of my_struct3. I am not sure if there is any guarantee in the standard that would cover you there, but I would not bet on it.

The advantages of separating out the common part in a separate structure type
are the following:

- This reduces repetition in your code which has the advantage of
  allowing  you to change the common code in one place, reducing the
  risk of errors.
- The compiler can check the types passed around, by
  casting the structs you would be effectively disabling such checks.
- There is no need for the common struct to be at the start of a struct, by making it a struct member the compiler can figure out the correct offsets for you.

---

```
struct common {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct my_struct1 {
   struct common com;
};

struct my_struct2 {
   struct common com;
   uint32_t d;
   uint32_t e;
};

struct my_struct3 {
   struct common com;
   uint16_t d;
   char e;
};

void init_common(struct common *com)
{
   com->a = 1;
   com->b = 2;
   /* ... */
}

struct my_struct1 s = {{1, 2, 3}};
struct my_struct2 p = {{1, 2, 3}, 4, 5};
struct my_struct3 q = {{1, 2, 3}, 4, 'a'};

init_common(&s.com);
init_common(&p.com);
init_common(&q.com);
```

Comment: Thanks for comments, I'll take advantage of this approach in a future work, however for now it is not possible, see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

It's semi-safe. If the first member is identical, you are guaranteed that a pointer to the structure is also a pointer to the first member. Technically, a compiler could insert arbitrary padding after the first member. In fact, no compiler will do so, so if two structs share a first and second member, the pointers to the second members also have the same offset. However the offset may not be address + sizeof(int) for your member "b". ints might e padded to 8 bytes for performance.

To avoid ambiguity, you can explicitly set the common members to a struct "common".

Comment: Your answer would be technically wrong, but practically debatable if the question was whether `my_struct_n*` could be cast to `my_struct_1*` safely. However, the question asks whether they can be cast to `my_struct_3*`, which contains members that `my_struct_1` does not contain, so even the alignment may be wrong. (Consider a machine where `sizeof(int) == 2` and `sizeof(uint32) == 4`).